# Push value in array and verify

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to select distinct value and push them into an array.
After that, i need to verify if a variable is situated into the array.

**Controller:**

```
$people = DB::table('checklists')->select('incaricato')->distinct()->get()->toArray();

if (in_array(\Auth::user()->id, $people)) {
    $variable = "yes";
}
```

Error:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int
```

Comment: Auth::user()->id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using `id` directly instead of going through `user`, like this:

```
if(in_array(Auth::id(), $people))
```

If it throws the same error, then dump that and check whats it returning

Comment: I did other check, and the problem is the array. 
Some advice? how can I create the array correctly?

Comment: What is the name of the column you wanna compare `user->id` to?

Comment: I would like to check if the user->id is inside an array. The array is created after making a select, selecting all user_id in a table. The column is "incaricato".

Comment: Try using `->pluck('incaricato')` instead of `->toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$people= \App\Checklist::distinct()->pluck('incaricato')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DB::table('checklists')->distinct()->pluck('incaricato')->toArray()
```